# Run a Python file with Ajax jQuery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I got a problem running a python file through jQuery. After searching on the internet I found a piece of code that calls a python script and run it.

The AJAX code for running the python script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scrape.py",
    data: { param: " "}, 
    dataType: "text"
    }).done(function( o ) {
        alert("OK");
});
```

In my python script(scrape.py) I have the following code:

```
import requests
body=requests.get('http://localhost/test/default.aspx?folder=test1')
print(body.text)
file = open("source/to/output/output.html","wb") #open file in binary mode
file.writelines(body)
file.close()
```

When I run this (in Firefox due to Cross domain policy problems) I get the following error: `syntax error` and it is pointing to my `import requests` import.

Anybody knows why this is and what I have to do to solve this?

Comment: You need a web server to handle your request, and dispatch it to your python script.

Comment: yep, indeed! thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you're getting error on the line:

```
import requests
```

You need to make sure whether requests module is installed in your computer. If not, try installing it using the following command on linux:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

If pip is not installed, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: This not a solution. The scrape.py works perfect if I load it through python. Therefore I know for sure that I installer requests. The problem lies within the combination of Ajax and Python. Nevertheless thanks for your answer